# Why is PCRE2 on Ubuntu installed in /usr/lib

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, pcre2

When I [install](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre2.html) PCRE2 on a Red Hat, PCRE2 is installed in **/usr/lib64**.

The libpcre2-8.so is 64 bit so it seems logical to install it in **/usr/lib64**.

However, when I do the same on Ubuntu 20.04, it installs it in **/usr/lib**. Why is that? Ubuntu is 64 bit, the libpcre2-8.so is 64 bit but the **make install** does install it in /usr/lib...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In debian based systems, they tend to use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, which, also clearly indicates 64 bit.

Not that it even matters, you could make a Linux OS with only 64 bit software supported and then why use 64 in any of the paths. Or maybe try NixOS where nothing is going to be installed into any standard paths at all.

> so it seems logical to install it in /usr/lib64

This just isn't a general rule across all distros.